# Space Invader's TextureLoader

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

So I'm having trouble learning how to load a texture into LWJGL OpenGL. So I went online and for learning purposes I copied the TextureLoader class from the Space Invaders example.

`URL url = TextureLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource(ref);`

I don't get what that does, where do I put the file that I want to load? It loads the resource into a BufferedImage using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(ref)`.

I tried putting the file in every folder there is with a class file in my bin and src.

I'm using Eclipse, if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: You need to put the files into a package.

Comment: an url is only the path to the file, you can use it to load the file. maybe this wil be of use for you? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the files into a package, or mainly into your projects source folder.

It's easier to show a picture of how this works than explaning it!

When you try to get a stream using `getResourceAsStream()` it will return null if it couldn't find the resource, if it found the resource it will return an instance of a `BufferInputStream`.

As you can see in the example right under, the first one returns an instance of `BufferedInputStream` when we try to get `file_1.txt`, thats because it exists, where it returns `null` when we try to get `file_2.txt` and that because it doesn't exist.

[image]

[Click here for fullscreen picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmQWx.png)